# Scrapy: the execution precedence

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using the following spider for crawling a website that requires an authentication.

```
import scrapy

class ImgData(scrapy.Item):
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "test"

   def start_requests(self):
       url = 'http://example.com/login'
       yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.loginpage)

   def loginpage(self, response):
       yield ImgData(image_urls=[response.xpath("//img[@id='CAPTCHA']/@src").extract()[0]])  #Line1
       captcha = input("-----> Enter the captcha in manually :") #Line2
       .
       .
       .
```

The problem is that Line2 executes before Line1. So despite the captcha not yet downloaded, it prompts to get captcha value by user!
What am I doing wrong and how I can solve the problem?

Comment: Perharps due to `yield` keyword the order is changed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this api but I did notice loginpage function is misspelled.  If that's a function you override it's probably why it's not getting called